# Broadcom BCM43225 can't connect to my home wifi

Tags: 12.10, broadcom

right now I don't have ubuntu installed because of this issue. The thing is that since ubuntu 11.04 ubuntu can't see my home wifi. I have an Acer aspire 5742 with a broadcom bcm 43225 wireless card. In ubuntu 10.10 the wifi worked perfectly, but since then I can connect everywhere but my home wifi.

I don't have changed anything in the configuration of the router. Now, with ubuntu 12.10 running from a live-usb it can see my wifi and connect to it, but when I start the install process, it disconnects and again can't see my wifi. Any ideas? Thanks for your help.

--EDIT--

Well, correct me if I'm wrong. I'm from Spain, and my router manual says that the wireless channel should be put in channel 13. With a little googling I discovered that the BCM43225 don't like channels from 12-14.

So, is there any problem if I change my wireless channel to channel 1? Is there any significant difference between channel 1 and 13 apart from the bandwidth?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anybody reaching here. The solution was changing my router channel to a channel less than 11. Then, it works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is set when the owner does not want to change the channel, or you are in a panel house where channels 12 and 13 are currency-loaded. In addition, Windows 10 can use these same channels without the slightest bug. This is a big bug in Linux.